# How to open .doc file using king office writer as default?

Tags: files, default-programs, doc

I downloaded King's Office .tar.xz file. Extracted it. I am able to run writer and open files by browsing for the .doc file.

I am not able to set the default application to king wps(writer) for doc files. 
When I am opening open with list of program, I cannot browse to wps and it is also not coming in list of application.

How can I set Kingoffice writer to be default?

Comment: i didn't installed it. i just downloaded the .tar.xz archive file from 
http://ksosoft.com/product/office-2013-linux.html

i extracted it and run the wps program file

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your username and home folder is *gman* and you have your King's Office software in */home/gman/ko*.

1. Go to your King's Office folder. `cd /home/gman/ko/` (`Ctrl+Alt+t` open terimanl )
2. Create a *.desktop* file`gedit kingsoffice.desktop` and edit it as:

   [Desktop Entry]

   Name=King's Office

   Exec=/home/gman/ko/ko.run (or what ever the name of the executable is)

   Terminal=false

   Type=Application

Finally make thi file executable `chmod +x kingsoffice.desktop` and copy it  `cp kingsoffice.desktop  /usr/share/applications`.Now you can set King's office as default. If you want you can even drag and drop the .desktop file to the launcher.
Then right click on a document go to **Properties** and to **Open With** and choose King's Office

Comment: If you allready have a .desktop file just make sure it has the %F under Exec and copy it to /usr/share/applications

Comment: I already have such a file called `wps-office-wps.desktop` under `/usr/share/applications` but LibreOffice opens .doc files. And I think, creating the file is not enough if file type is already associated with another application such as LibreOffice. In addition to @Daniel's answer,
I right clicked a .doc file and clicked `Properties`, then `Open With` tab. I selected `WPS Writer` from the list and clicked `Set as Default`